# Order of php variables in file

Tags: php, variables

This may sound weird. I need the simplest way to register the order of variables in a php file. Let me give you an example:

Lets say you define 3 variables:

```
<?php
$adam = 'the yes man';
$ben = 'the hard worker';
$john = 'the slave';
?>
```

In another php file, you need to know the order of these variables (you know the variables are adam, ben and john, but you don't know if it's that order they were typed in). Without extending with too much code around the variables, how can you know the order?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all the good answers. The solution came in an extend of what @blackpla9ue said.

Made an array instead and can now cycle through the positions (0->1->2->3->...).

```
<?php
   $array = array(
   'adam' => 'the yes man',
   'ben' => 'the hard worker',
   'john' => 'the slave'
   )
<?

<?php
   $array_pos = array_keys($array);

   $person1 = $array_pos[0];
   $person1_is = $array[$array_pos[0]];
?>
```

You can also use:

```
<?php  
   foreach ($array as $key => $value)
      statement
?>
```

Comment: Why not use an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead?

Comment: I'm using it to make my own development faster in future time. Mostly for test purpose at the moment. Only by experimenting can you push your production level further. It's not always preferable to mention the whole background. Some prefer to read my life story others don't. Easy with the -1 pall.

Comment: Yes, this should not be downvoted, it's still a valid and interesting question as shown by [chelmertz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9556143/327317), though the usage of this approach is quite limited to the edge cases (arrays should be used for everyday needs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use an `array`

```
$users = array('adam' => 'the yes man',
               'ben' => 'the hard worker',
               'john' => 'the slave');
```

When you want to get the positions, use,

```
$positions = array_keys($users);

echo array_search('ben', $positions); // 1
echo array_search('john', $positions); // 2
```

Comment: Great. This did lead to my choice of a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a function called [`get_defined_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) which gives you an array containing all your defined variables in the order they were defined.

Try it out:

```
<?php
$prev = get_defined_vars();
$ben = 'the hard worker';
$adam = 'the yes man';
$john = 'the slave';
# removing the builtin stuff you get, like $_REQUEST and such
var_dump(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $prev));
```

Comment: This could lead to a solution, but it just ended up being too hairy. Used @blackpla9ue 's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Store them in an array.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'adam'=>'the yes man', 
'ben'=>'the hard worker', 
'john'=>'the slave'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the first script where you declare these varaibles you can add

```
<?php
$order = array();
$adam = 'the yes man';
$order[] = 'admin';
$ben = 'the hard worker';
$order[] = 'ben';
$john = 'the slave';
$order[] = 'john';
?>
```

in the second script you can use array_search to find the order of the declaration.